# Regex: shortest match not happening

Tags: r, regex

I would like to extract `"/arsenal-vs-man-city/"` from `"/sports/football/arsenal-vs-man-city/stats/"`. I can't understand why what I'm trying isn't working. I don't know why I'm getting the long start, given that I'm asking for short with `?` on both sides of `-vs-`. Here's the reprex:

```r
library(stringr)
str_extract_all("/sports/football/arsenal-vs-man-city/stats/", "/.*?-vs-.*?/")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "/sports/football/arsenal-vs-man-city/"
```

I'd like to know what the correct way to do this is and also why my way is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex matches the first `/`, then *any* 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the first (leftmost) occurrence of `-vs-` and then any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the closest leftmost `/`.

You need to "restrict" the first `.` at least to match any char but `/`, and you may use a *negated* bracket expression approach like:

```
/[^/]*-vs-[^/]*/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dhCPSb/1)

**Details**

- `/` - a `/`
- `[^/]*` - 0 or more chars other than `/`
- `-vs-` - a literal substring
- `[^/]*`  - 0 or more chars other than `/`
- `/`  - a `/`.

R test:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract_all("/sports/football/arsenal-vs-man-city/stats/", "/[^/]*-vs-[^/]*/")
[[1]]
[1] "/arsenal-vs-man-city/"
```